# Document @ApiOperation with long detailed description

Tags: jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui

While documenting an operation using [@ApiOperation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-annotations/src/main/java/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiOperation.java), there is the `notes` atribute for a long description of the operation. But putting a long description in the annotation makes it cumbersome and difficult to mantain.

Is there a more elegant option to reference an external file or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't right now, no. At best, I could recommend using a string constant as an input to the `@ApiOperation` and keep it elsewhere to avoid the clutter. Another option would be to use the externalDocs if you're on swagger-core 1.5.